Wolfram Alpha app in Windows error message
I haven't used the Wolfram Alpha app in Windows for years until today, and when I open it now I just get the following error message:

Error: Something went wrong while trying to load that information. Please try again.

How can I get the app working again?
Yeah, I reinstalled the app, without any change. I have the latest build of Windows 11. I don't have the resources to try it on another computer.

Are you looking for assistance solving a problem, or just whether anyone else has observed the same/similar behavior? Please note that the latter question is off topic here, while the former is more on-topic, but will require that you add more information to your post and change the question you are asking in it. This site isn't really about "is anyone else having X problem", but is about "X is happening, I've tried Y to resolve it but have failed, how do I get Z to happen?"

@music2myear What should I do if my post is off-topic?

Wolfram|Alpha on the Microsoft Store not working anymore on the Wolfram community has two users reporting the same Error: Something went wrong while trying to load that information. Please try again. error message. There is no solution given, only the suggestion to email windows-support@wolframalpha.com

“ Is it possible that the problem is caused by malware?” - No

Have you removed and reinstalled the app? What version/build of Windows are you running? Have you tried running the app on a different computer?

Can you add that info to the question? It'll make the question a lot better.

Moved the comment back to the question.

Use something like Wireshark to confirm the application is attempting to communicate with the external server
